# My HC-SR501 motion sensor for stm32f10x board is always showing 0(motion is not detected)

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

This code should get the input value from the Motion Sensor HC-SR501(either 0/1) and show it on the LCD-display. Everything is connected to the stm32f10x board. I guess there is a code logic mistake and it always prints 0. Or is there any connection problems?

'''

```
 #include <stdbool.h>
    #include "stm32f10x.h"
    #include "stm32f10x_exti.h"
    #include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
    #include "stm32f10x_usart.h"
    #include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"
    #include "core_cm3.h"
    #include "stm32f10x_adc.h"
    #include "lcd.h"
    #include "touch.h"
    #include "misc.h"

    /* function prototype */
    void RCC_Configure(void);
    void GPIO_Configure(void);
    void USART1_Init(void);
    void USART2_Init(void);
    void NVIC_Configure(void);

    void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void);

    uint16_t value, x, y;
    bool motionDetected = false;
    int color[12] = {WHITE, CYAN, BLUE, RED, MAGENTA, LGRAY, GREEN, YELLOW, BROWN, BRRED, GRAY};
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    void RCC_Configure(void)
    {
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC,ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1,ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA,ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);
    }


    void GPIO_Configure(void)
    {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AIN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    }


    void ADC_Configure(void) {
            ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_12;
            ADC_12.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
            ADC_12.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
            ADC_12.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_None;
    ADC_12.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent;
    ADC_12.ADC_NbrOfChannel = 1;
    ADC_12.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;

    ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_12);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_12, 1, ADC_SampleTime_239Cycles5);
    ADC_ITConfig(ADC1,ADC_IT_EOC, ENABLE);
    ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
    ADC_ResetCalibration(ADC1);
    while(ADC_GetResetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));
    ADC_StartCalibration(ADC1);
    while(ADC_GetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));
    ADC_SoftwareStartConvCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
    }


    void EXTI_Configure(void)
    {
        EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;

        GPIO_EXTILineConfig(GPIO_PortSourceGPIOE, GPIO_PinSource8);
        EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line8;
        EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
        EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Falling;
        EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
        EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);
    }


    void NVIC_Configure(void) {

        NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

        NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_1); // need modify

        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = ADC1_2_IRQn;
        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
        NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI9_5_IRQn;
        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x0; // TODO
        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x0; // TODO
        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
        NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    }

    void ADC1_2_IRQHandler() {
    if(ADC_GetITStatus(ADC1,ADC_IT_EOC) != RESET) {
    value = ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1);
            }
    ADC_ClearITPendingBit(ADC1, ADC_IT_EOC);
    }

    
    void delay(uint32_t t) {
      for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {}
    }


    void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void) {
        if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line8) != RESET) {
            if (GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_8) != Bit_RESET) {
              if (!motionDetected)  { motionDetected = true; }
            }
            EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line8);
        }
    }




    int main(void)
    {

        SystemInit();

        RCC_Configure();

        GPIO_Configure();

        ADC_Configure();

        //EXTI_Configure();

        NVIC_Configure();

        LCD_Init();
        Touch_Configuration();
        Touch_Adjust();
        LCD_Clear(WHITE);

        while (1) {
    /*
    if 사운드 < threshold:
      블루투스로 전송
    IF MOSITION == 1:
      블루투스로 전송

    */
            uint32_t inputData = GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0);
            LCD_ShowNum(0, 0, (uint32_t) inputData, 10, BLACK, WHITE);
            LCD_ShowNum(80,120,value,4,BLACK,WHITE);
            if (motionDetected) {
                  motionDetected = false;
                  LCD_ShowString(80, 150, "motion detected", BLACK, WHITE);
            }
            else {
                  LCD_ShowString(80, 150, "motion not detected", BLACK, WHITE);
            }
            
            //delay(1000000);
        }
       return 0;
    }
```

'''

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler()`, does it ever get hit?